# does ArrayList and random numbers needs a library in c#?

Tags: c#, arraylist, random

I am unable to declare random numbers and ArrayList. It shows a red line beneath these key words. even though I am able to print things like how c# does.

What could be the possible problem?
I installed vs2017 and started using it yesterday. wrote a simple program and it worked fine.

here is the code abd the error

code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
namespace Question3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] rand_array = new int[2000000];
            int num = random.Next();
            ArrayList arrlist = new ArrayList();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: There is no class called `random`, there's only `Random`. Also you could just search which assemblies those classes are declared in

Comment: Also don't confuse classes with keywords, neither `Random` nor `ArrayList` are keywords. And `ArrayList` shouldn't be used in C# anyway

Comment: why are you saying that ArrayList shouldn't be used in c#? please justify.

Comment: Because Microsoft does not recommend using it. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: You never even declare `random`.

Comment: Also, `ArrayList` is in the `System.Collections` namespace, which you don't have a `using` statement for.

Comment: *Do* read the messages VS provides you: `...are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?` A: Yes you are.  And *always* consult the documentation the first time you use a new object/class like `Random` to learn for certain how it works rather than guessing or assuming.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that is not defined within your scope will need to be imported by the `using` statement.

In order to use `ArrayList` you need to reference to the namespace by  adding `using System.Collections;`

In order to use `Random` you need to reference to the namespace by  adding `using System;`

Before you can use an instance of an object you must declare and initialise it. For example in your code you are using `random.Next();` random has not been declared - therefore how the compiler will know what `random` is ?

Here is the code refactored:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
namespace Question3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int[] randArray = new int[2000000];
            int num = random.Next();
            ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        }
    }
}
```